# External monitor is disabled after resume (only on 15.04)

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, monitor, 15.04

I recently installed ubuntu 15.04 and most things just work out of the box, awesome!

But there is on annoying thing: I have an external screen connected to my machine (T450s, via docking station) and **after resuming from suspend, my external monitor is disabled**.

After some trial and error I made an interesting observation: The external monitor only stops working if suspend via `systemctl suspend`, `sudo pm-suspend`, or via the hotkey on my keyboard (K750).

However, this problem does **not** occur if I suspend via the menu entry in the upper right corner.

How is this even possible?

Mapping the suspend command from the upper right corner to a hotkey would be a sufficient workaround. But which command is used by that button?

fyi: this problem does not occur on ubuntu 14.04.

If anyone is interested, there is a bugreport on launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1454160

Answer (score 2):

I have the same configuration and problem. One workaround I found is to go to one virtual terminal (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and then go back to the desktop (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>).

Comment: I have this same problem in Ubuntu 14.04 but after the screen goes to sleep. I'm on a desktop so I don't use suspend or hibernate, or maybe suspend is kicking in automatically and I don't know how to disable it.